# Data Average Not Close to the Age I chose

Tags: r

I have a function called sim.LifeAnnuity, which takes three parameters nsim (number of samples), a (age) and g (Gender of either Male of Female). There is another table that I am drawing data from called LifeTable. This table ranges from ages 0 to 119. The function is supposed to return the number of payments purchased by an individual of age = a and gender (Male of Female). The probability is impacted by the gender and age, where it should take into consideration the prob values from age (a to 119). This is the my code thus far:

```
sim.lifeAnnuity <- function(nsim, a, g = c("Female", "Male")) {
                age <- c(1:(120-a))
                malep <- c(Lab1$Male_Prob[(a+1):120])
                falep <- c(Lab1$Female_Prob[(a+1):120])
                if(a>=0 & a<=119 & g=="Male") {
                 male <- sample(age, size = nsim, replace = TRUE, prob = 
                 malep)
                 return(male)
            }
                if(a>=0 & a<=119 & g=="Female") {
                  female <- sample(age, size = nsim, replace = TRUE, prob = 
                  falep)
                  return(female)
        }
```

}
sim.lifeAnnuity(nsim = 5, a = 40, g = "Male")

I created two vectors malep and femalep and utilized them in sample(). The return outcome should give a vector of nsim payments, whose average should be close to the age I pick. However the values I receive are not close to the age I chose.

Comment: "the error came up still" --- what was the error? What is your expected output?

Comment: Expected Output should be a vector returning a set of payments. So if I set nsim = 5, age = 40, g = "Male" it should return something like [1] 38 66 73 63 61. I did change up the code since then. I created two vectors called malep and femalep. Used these to represent the prob in sample. And set them as c(LifeTable$Male_Prob[a:119]) based on the gender. However the average of the output should be close to the age I chose.